# Стоит ли использовать асинхронность при добавлении нового пользователя в БД?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, асинхронность

Когда пользователь первый раз запускает Телеграм-бота, его необходимо добавить в базу данных MySQL. Стоит ли использовать асинхронные запросы в Entity Framework Core для того, чтобы реализовать это?

Comment: При любых I/O операциях стоит использовать асинхронность

Comment: Вообще, асинхронность может снизить производительность одного запроса, но сильно увеличивает общую пропускную способность системы. / Провайдеры некоторых СУБД до сих пор синхронные внутри, хоть и выставляют наружу асинхронный интерфейс. Насчёт провайдера MySql не знаю.